# Django allauth password reset doesn't work when clicking the link from email, but works otherwise

Tags: html, django, external, django-allauth, django-sessions

### What is supposed to happen:

The request is completely handled by the [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) package which is supposed to detect the token, save it to the session, redirect to the 'change your password' page, and finally load the token from the session.

### The problem:

The password reset function does not work when clicking the link from the email (Bad Token), but if I copy-paste the link into the url bar or click the href in Inspect Element mode it DOES work.
Note: It also works if

- I reload the page after seeing "Bad Token"
- I click the link from inside an email app on my mobile device

### The error:

When you click the link from your email you make it all the way to the 'change your password' page but you get a "Bad Token" error as no Token was found in the session.

### Format of the link emailed to the user:

```
<a href="https://subdomain.url.com/ls/click?upn=DEcd6nIgEEAvb4Zt..." rel="noreferrer" safedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://sudomain.url.com/...">link text</a>
```

For clarification, both the href and the safedirecturl work fine if I copy-paste it into the url bar

### Conclusion:

So far, these are my only guesses at the cause of the issue:

- An external website is referring the user to the page.

  - The safedirecturl works which seems to contradict this.
- The token is not saved in the session in time (race condition?)

  - This seems unlikely to me since [in django-allauth source code I saw that the token is set in the session before the final redirect](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/ced1ddc730c36eca3551406c60e1577e30e01cbd/allauth/account/views.py#L722).

I would greatly appreciate any input as I'm a bit stumped at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in my django settings I had `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`, I had to change `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'` to `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'`